# Move page numbering to top left

Tags: page-numbering

I want the number of the page was at the top of the page and in the left corner. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that doesn't rely on a specialized package. It does assume, though, that either the `article` document class or one of the other "standard" document classes is in use. (Specifically, the document class in use has to provide, at a minimum, the macros `\pagestyle` and `\ps@headings`...) You need to insert the following code in the document's preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox} % provides \patchcmd macro
\makeatletter % modify the "headings" page style
\patchcmd{\ps@headings}{{\slshape\rightmark}\hfil\thepage}{\thepage\hfil}{}{}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{headings}  % load the (re-defined) "headings" page style (default: "plain")
```

Answer (score 3):

```
%\documentclass{report}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}

\fancyhead[LO, LE]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt} 

\begin{document}

\section{AA}    

E: Even page
O: Odd page
L: Left field
C: Center field
R: Right field
H: Header
F: Footer


\newpage

\section{BB}

E: Even page
O: Odd page
L: Left field
C: Center field
R: Right field
H: Header
F: Footer


\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have \documentclass{article}. Will it work?

Comment: Yes. `Report` and `book` are two-sided, so an example for one of them.

Comment: It does underline, and even a section title. I want only the page number.

Comment: `\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}`

Comment: How to make only the number of the page  was on the left and on the top.

Comment: Still is the title of the section to the right of the page number.

Comment: Not all commands copied I. My mistake.

Comment: zauważyłam że jak coś wpisze polecenie \fancyhead{} to tworzy ono nagłówek ale dubluje mi ten nagłówek (pisze go pośrodu i po prawej na górze) i chce go również zmodyfikować: \titleformat*{\fancyhead}{\scshape\centering} ale to nie działa ... ratuj